# Memory leak in QTcpServer attending connections in different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm developing a RPC server in Qt 4.7 on Windows 7.
In order to attend several executions at the same time every request run in a separate thread (as functions might be blocking). I inherited from QTcpServer and reimplemented  the incomingConnection function, it looks like this:

```
void RpcServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor){
    QThread *thread = new QThread();
    RpcServerConnection *client = new RpcServerConnection(socketDescriptor);
    client->moveToThread(thread);    
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), client, SLOT(init()));
    connect(client, SIGNAL(finish()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

RpcServerConnection managed data exchange. The init method looks like this:

```
 void RpcServerConnection::init(){
        qDebug() << "ServerSocket(" << QThread::currentThreadId() << "): Init";
        clientConnection = new QTcpSocket();
        clientConnection->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);

        connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readFromSocket()));
        connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(finish()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    }
```

Once all data is received and response is sent, finish signal is emited.
Debugging I can see that all threads and sockets are deleted. However, process memory increases with every new connection and it is not freed when it ends...

Do I have to free anything else when inheriting from QTcpServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be with a race/undefined calling order. `RpcServerConnection::finish()` is connected both to its `deleteLater()` slot, and to the thread's `quit()` slot. If the thread's `quit` slot is entered first, the thread will terminate immediately from the event loop, before anything can be done about the deferred deletion.

Instead of:

```
connect(client, SIGNAL(finish()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
```

try:

```
connect(client, SIGNAL(destroyed()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
```